# Matplotlib: how do I know which colormap is being used?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I played around with colormaps, trying many of them, trying to make my own, both in matplotlib and seaborn.

However now I would like to know which colormap I am using. How can I do that? Is there a command like `matplotlib.whichColormap` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually there would be no need to find out the colormap you are using because you define that yourself. I.e. when calling

```
plt.imshow(..., cmap="viridis")
```

you already know that you are using "viridis".

If you still feel it would be useful to get that information from an existing ScalarMappable, you may use `get_cmap()` and it's `name` attribute:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(4,5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(a, cmap="viridis")

cm = im.get_cmap()
print(cm.name)  # prints viridis
```

Comment: Thanks. However this doesn't work in the case I use `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'gold', 'limegreen'])` for instance. Because when I do that, I just get something like: `<matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap at 0x8b90fd0>` which means nothing to me..

Comment: Sure, but what would you expect to get instead?

Comment: well something containing the information `['red', 'gold', 'limegreen']` for instance the actual list or some other object//

Comment: `<matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap at 0x8b90fd0>` *is* an object. What object do you want other than the one that you ask for? You can get the colors via `cm.colors`, but since most inbuilt colormaps have 256 colors, you will get a very long list out.